# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch') Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Trying to get 10 messages from every channel in a guild and read the contents then see if they contain a certain string but getting the error below

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
```

This is my code

```
interaction.guild.channels.cache.forEach(c => {
   c.messages.fetch({limit: 10}).then(msgs => {
      msgs.forEach(m => {
         if (m.content.includes(interaction.options.getString('text',true))) {
            // will do stuff here
         }
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
   })
})
```

Comment: ive read up on discord.js wiki and it says you can do this [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Comment: Is `c.messages` defined? Try `console.log(c.messages)` just before `c.messages.fetch`.

Comment: alr ill try to do it

Comment: yes i just console logged it and it printed all the normal info sent

Comment: What intents did you provide when creating the client?

Comment: currently the bot has all intents as its just in 1 server

Comment: So you have something like this: `const client = new discord.Client({
    intents: [
      discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
      discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
  });` ?

Comment: im using an intents calculator [here](https://ziad87.net/intents/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck too. Hopefully some one else comes along.

Comment: ok well thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`interaction.guild.channels.cache` is a collection of [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildChannel).

GuildChannels combines all theses categories of channels.

[image: channels]

Unfortunately, only [Text Channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel) and [News Channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/NewsChannel) have a `messages` property.

Maybe you need to check this condition before fetch the messages.

```js
interaction.guild.channels.cache.forEach(c => {
   if(c.type == 'GUILD_TEXT'){
      c.messages.fetch({limit: 10}).then(msgs => {
         msgs.forEach(m => {
            if (m.content.includes(interaction.options.getString('text',true))) {
               // will do stuff here
            }
         }).catch(err => console.error(err))
      })
   }
})
```

You can also filter the channels

```js
interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter((c) => c.type == 'GUILD_TEXT').forEach(c => {
   c.messages.fetch({limit: 10}).then(msgs => {
      msgs.forEach(m => {
         if (m.content.includes(interaction.options.getString('text',true))) {
            // will do stuff here
         }
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
   })
})
```

Comment: alr ill have a look see if this fixes it